# Store json data as array in database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm working on a project where user can fill out his/her profile. So while storing user's social media links, I've a json file which has all the refrences like name, favicon, url. So I can foreach it using json_decode and display with a text field. But how do I store all the links entered in the database as json format and retrieve them with the full URL.

This is json file

```
{
  "facebook": {
    "icon": "fab fa-facebook",
    "title": "Facebook",
    "url": "https://facebook.com/%s"
  },
  "instagram": {
    "icon": "fab fa-instagram",
    "title": "Instagram",
    "url": "https://instagram.com/%s"
  }
}
```

This is how I'm displaying it

```
 <?php foreach($available_buttons as $key => $button):  ?>
       <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label ><i class="<?= $button->icon ?> mr-2"></i> <?= $button->title ?></label>
                 <input type="text" name="buttons[<?= $key ?>]" class="form-control" />
            </div>
       </div
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I'm processing it by using json_encode annd submitting it to db

```
$buttons = json_encode(clean_array($_POST['buttons']));
```

Passing the data in clean array function

```
function clean_array(Array $data) {
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key] = filter_var($data, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }

    return $data;
}
```

But when I try to submit i get false in database like "{'instagram': 'false', 'instagram': 'false'}"

How do I do it?

Comment: post name is not correct "buttons[<?= $key ?>]" . You are passing the name with dynamic value, but you are saving the result with not matching that name "$_POST['buttons']"

Comment: Instead of using echo for $key, you can simply wrap it with an equal sign to echo it <?= $key ?>, not an issue

Comment: I'm not telling about the echo function.  telling about dynamic values in name

Comment: Question edited

Comment: please check your $_POST['buttons'] values after submit the form, and show us

Answer (score 2):

You can store data as JSON in database and then get it again from database and convert it with json_decode. MySQL support JSON data type. Take a look on this link.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Answer (score 1):

filter_var() can return FALSE when failed, check documentation:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

As first argument you should pass scalar or string, but you pass array $data (array is not scalar), therefore filter_var fails and returns false.
Maybe you want to pass $value?

E.g. example of how your function should look like

```
function clean_array(Array $data) {
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key] = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }

    return $data;
}
```